# List Returns firts Item of Duplicates Work Around Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Good[ Morning : Evening ]

Im trying to make a small programme that :

-reads a text file containing numbers -assigned each line into an element of int_list

-takes a given list (**max_quantity**) and divides all the elements by 2 resulting in (**max_q_in_half**)

- takes (**int_lis**t) and compares each element to its counterpart in (**max_q_in_half**) to eliminate each element that is above 50% of its maximum value (**max_quantity**)

-then make all the elements that are below 50% of their maximum value
into a new list (**new_list**)

-then return the smallest number in the (**new_list**)

-then uses that number to get it's index in the original (**int_list**)

-then uses that index to match the number to it's element in (**metal_list**)

- to return the metal that is about to run out from the stock so the it could  be restocked

**HERE IS THE PROBLME**

As you see in the output of this code the numbers below 50% are **[41, 1]**
the lowest value is **1** which has the index ***6***

but when i search *int_list* for this value it returns the firt occurence of **1** which is at index ***3*** which coresponds to **BRASS** but the correct answer should be **Titanium**

im triying to work around this issue by assigning a weight to each line in the text file so when i search the index of a value that value would be unique
take into account that the lines vary in number in the original text file

could somebody help me make a programe that assignes wheights of X.01 to line one and X.02 to line two ...

-41.**01** #Line_**1**

-20.**02** #Line_**2**

-6.**03** #Line_**3**

-1.**04** #Line_**4**

-14.**05** #Line_**5**

-6.**06** #Line_**6**

-1.**07** #Line_**7**
...

```
int_list = [41, 20, 6, 1, 14, 6, 1]

metal_list = ['aluminium', 'iron', 'zinc', 'brass', 'stainless steel','copper', 'titanium']

max_quantity = [ 100, 30, 6, 2, 18, 7, 15]

max_q_in_half = [x // 2 for x in max_quantity]


new_list = [i for i, j in zip(int_list, max_q_in_half) if i < j]

x = min(new_list)

v = int_list.index(x)
w = metal_list.__getitem__(v)


print("Current List ", int_list)

print("what is below 50%",new_list)
print('lowest value ',x)


print("position in int_list  ",v)

print("position Metal_list ",w)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the elements of the list by 2 when checking. It is better to number it when creating a list, but with the second member, so that the number does not interfere when checking for a minimum.

```
int_list = [41, 20, 6, 1, 14, 6, 1]
metal_list = ['aluminium', 'iron', 'zinc', 'brass', 'stainless steel', 'copper', 'titanium']
max_quantity = [100, 30, 6, 2, 18, 7, 15]

x = min([(i, n) for n, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(int_list, max_quantity)) if i < j//2])
print(x)
w = metal_list[x[1]]
print("position Metal_list ", w)

(1, 6)
position Metal_list  titanium
```

Comment: this is a cool and elegant solution thank you very much although i still quite don't understand what you did there

Comment: @AnasseGs I created a list of numbered tuples (of elements that matched the condition), where the position of the element is its "weight", as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this i appreciate your kindness thank you